# Understanding aiohttp.TCPConnector pooling & connection limits

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am experimenting with the `limit` and `limit_per_host` parameters to `aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector`.

In the script below, I pass `connector = aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector(limit=25, limit_per_host=5)` to `aiohttp.ClientSession`, then open 2 requests to docs.aiohttp.org and 3 to github.com.

The result of `session.request` is an instance of `aiohttp.ClientResponse`, and in this example I intentionally do not call `.close()` on it, either via `.close()` or `__aexit__`.  I would assume this would leave the connection pool open and decrease the available connections to that (host, ssl, port) triple by -1.

The table below represents the `._available_connections()` after each request.  **Why does the number hang at 4 even after completing the 2nd request to docs.aiohttp.org?**  Both of these connections are presumably still open and haven't accessed `._content` yet or been closed.  Shouldn't the available connections decrease by 1?

```
After Request Num.        To                    _available_connections
1                         docs.aiohttp.org      4
2                         docs.aiohttp.org      4   <--- Why?
3                         github.com            4
4                         github.com            3
5                         github.com            2
```

Furthermore, **why does `._acquired_per_host` only ever contain 1 key?**  I guess I may be understanding the methods of [`TCPConnector`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/connector.py); what explains the behavior above?

Full script:

```
import aiohttp


async def main():
    connector = aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector(limit=25, limit_per_host=5)

    print("Connector arguments:")
    print("_limit:", connector._limit)
    print("_limit_per_host:", connector._limit_per_host)
    print("-" * 70, end="\n\n")

    async with aiohttp.client.ClientSession(
        connector=connector,
        headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2225.0 Safari/537.36"},
        raise_for_status=True
    ) as session:

        # Make 2 connections to docs.aiohttp.org and 
        #      3 connections to github.com
        #
        # Note that these instances intentionally do not use
        # .close(), either explicitly or via __aexit__
        # in an async with block

        r1 = await session.request(
            "GET",
            "https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#connectors"
        )
        print_connector_attrs("r1", session)

        r2 = await session.request(
            "GET",
            "https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/index.html"
        )
        print_connector_attrs("r2", session)

        r3 = await session.request(
            "GET",
            "https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/client.py"
        )
        print_connector_attrs("r3", session)

        r4 = await session.request(
            "GET",
            "https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/typing.py"
        )
        print_connector_attrs("r4", session)

        r5 = await session.request(
            "GET",
            "https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp"
        )
        print_connector_attrs("r5", session)


def print_connector_attrs(name: str, session: aiohttp.client.ClientSession):
    print("Connection attributes for", name, end="\n\n")
    conn = session._connector
    print("_conns:", conn._conns, end="\n\n")
    print("_acquired:", conn._acquired, end="\n\n")
    print("_acquired_per_host:", conn._acquired_per_host, end="\n\n")
    print("_available_connections:")
    for k in conn._acquired_per_host:
        print("\t", k, conn._available_connections(k))
    print("-" * 70, end="\n\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import asyncio
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The output is pasted at https://pastebin.com/rvfzMTe3.  I've put it there rather than here because the lines are long and not very wrap-able.

Comment: Just off the top of my head; you have aiohttp connection pooling, but also connection reusage and keep-alives. Could the latter mess up your script's count?

Comment: @ElToro1966 I thought to look there too, but it looks like the default keep-alive time is 15.0 seconds.  So that would not come into play here, it seems?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To address your main question “Why does the number hang at 4 even after completing the 2nd request to docs.aiohttp.org?”, 
the connection count will be decreased when `aiohttp.connector.BaseConnector._release()` is called and this would be called if you were to use the `async with` on `session.request()`
or explicitly call `.close()` or after you read the response content with `.read()`. Or as it is in the case of docs.aiohttp.org requests when the server send an EOF (this happens when the server does not wait for you to stream the response content but send it all in response to the first request). And this is what is happening here. You can see for yourself when you put a breakpoint in the  `aiohttp.connector.BaseConnector._release()` and examine the stack, you will see that `aiohttp.http_parser.DeflateBuffer.feed_eof()` is called. And that `aiohttp.streams.StreamReade._eof_callbacks` contains `aiohttp.client_reqrep.ClientResponse._response_eof()` that is calling `self._connection.release()`

As for your second question “why does `._acquired_per_host` only ever contain 1 key”, well it is odd. But I can not see nothing about it in the doc. It is a private attribute so we should not mess with it. It is probably just badly named private attribute.